# Unable to run nano with sudo using urxvt terminal emulator on remote system

Tags: centos, arch-linux, terminal, zsh, rxvt

I have an Arch laptop running i3-wm and urvxt. When I attempt to remotely connect to my CentOS 7 (zsh + oh-my-zsh) server through ssh and run the command `sudo nano` I receive the following error message:

```
frankserver-centos ➜  ~ echo $TERM                                                                                                                                
rxvt-unicode-256color
frankserver-centos ➜  ~ nano                                                                                                                                      
frankserver-centos ➜  ~ sudo nano                                                                                                                                 
Error opening terminal: rxvt-unicode-256color.
```

Initially, I was completely unable to run nano at all, and received the terminal opening error every time.

I resolved this by following instructions from [here](http://alemani.com/urxvt-unknown-terminal-type-with-ssh/):

> First create the directory to keep the terminfo file in the server:
>
> `mkdir -p ~/.terminfo/r`
>
> Next, copy the matching file found on your local machine to the server, for urxvt-unicode-256color would be:
>
> `scp /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-unicode-256color user@server.com:.terminfo/r`

How can I achieve the same result for issuing commands with `sudo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just this:

```
infocmp rxvt-unicode-256color >foo
sudo tic foo
```

(which will install the terminal description for all users, even **`root`**).

Comment: Perfect! I'll take a look at what this does a bit later, but it seems to work how I want it to now. Thanks